# Why does rem_euclid return different results using parenthesis in rust?

Tags: rust

i was making some experiments with rust and i noticed that the rem_euclid() function returns different results when using parenthesis around the number on which the function is called.

can someone please explain me why is that?

```
fn main() {
print!("{}", (-16_64).rem_euclid(10)); // prints 4
}
```

```
fn main() {
print!("{}", -16_64.rem_euclid(10)); // prints -6
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rem_euclid()` is not supposed to return a negative number.
The second one is getting the remainder of `16_64`, then getting the negative of the number.
Example:

```rust
fn main() {
    print!("{}", -16_64.rem_euclid(10));
    // is the same as...
    print!("{}", -(16_64.rem_euclid(10)));
}
```